# Search Text in Table and Click Link on different column Using Watir

Tags: ruby, selenium, automation, webdriver, watir

I have the following HTML table.
[image]
Is there a way in Watir to click the "Bin" logo of the name "TestingName1"?
Can Watir search for the text "test" and click the "bin" logo after that?

The following is the HTML

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
<colgroup>
    <col class=""><col class="" style="width: 100px; min-width: 100px;">
    <col class="" style="width: 100px; min-width: 100px;">
</colgroup>
<tbody>
    <tr class="">
        <td tabindex="1" class="" style="text-align: left;">Distributor</td>
        <td tabindex="2" class="" style="text-align: center;">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="ant-checkbox-wrapper">
                    <span class="ant-checkbox ant-checkbox-checked ant-checkbox-disabled">
                        <input disabled="" class="ant-checkbox-input" value="on" type="checkbox">
                        <span class="ant-checkbox-inner"></span>
                    </span>
                </label>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td tabindex="3" class="" style="text-align: center;">
            <div>
                <a id="lnkEditVendor" class="btn btn-default btn-xs" disabled="">
                    <i class="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </a>
                <!-- react-text: 762 -->&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<!-- /react-text -->
                <a id="lnkDeleteVendor" class="btn btn-default btn-xs" disabled="">
                    <i class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </a>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="">
        <td tabindex="4" class="" style="text-align: left;">testFMM</td>
        <td tabindex="5" class="" style="text-align: center;">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="ant-checkbox-wrapper">
                    <span class="ant-checkbox ant-checkbox-checked">
                        <input class="ant-checkbox-input" value="on" type="checkbox">
                        <span class="ant-checkbox-inner">
                            </span>
                        </span>
                    </label>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td tabindex="6" class="" style="text-align: center;">
                <div>
                    <a id="lnkEditVendor" class="btn btn-default btn-xs">
                        <i class="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    </a>
                    <!-- react-text: 777 -->&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<!-- /react-text -->
                    <a id="lnkDeleteVendor" class="btn btn-default btn-xs">
                        <i class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="">
            <td tabindex="7" class="" style="text-align: left;">TestingName1</td>
            <td tabindex="8" class="" style="text-align: center;">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="ant-checkbox-wrapper">
                        <span class="ant-checkbox ant-checkbox-checked">
                            <input class="ant-checkbox-input" value="on" type="checkbox">
                            <span class="ant-checkbox-inner"></span>
                        </span>
                    </label>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td tabindex="9" class="" style="text-align: center;">
                <div>
                    <a id="lnkEditVendor" class="btn btn-default btn-xs">
                        <i class="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    </a>
                    <!-- react-text: 792 -->&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<!-- /react-text -->
                    <a id="lnkDeleteVendor" class="btn btn-default btn-xs">
                        <i class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
     </tbody>
</table>
```

I have tried to check if the text I want exists on the table

```
ary = driver.table(:class => ["table table-striped table-bordered table-hover"]).trs.collect{ |tr| tr[0].text }
  ary.each do |i|
     logger.info i
      if i == "#{name1}"
        logger.info "The data entered as #{name1} found"
      end
  end
```

I am still unable to click the "bin" button on the right that belongs to the text "TestingName1".

Thank you.

Comment: Watir can do that. Though without the HTML, it's difficult to give you an actual solution.

Comment: Please read [ask], especially the part about [mcve] (MCVE), and [How much research effort is expected?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) This will help you debug your own programs and solve problems for yourself. If you do this and are still stuck you can come back and post your MCVE, what you tried, and the execution result including any error messages so we can better help you. Also provide a link to the page and/or the relevant HTML.

Comment: As a side note: The HTML you included above is not valid as ID values are repeated.  To be valid legal HTML ID's must be unique within the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking at the answer from Chuck van der Linden above, I modified it a bit and got a working code as follow:

```
table = driver.table(:class => ["table table-striped table-bordered table-hover"])
  textRow = table.td(:text => "TestingName1").parent
  if textRow.a(:id => "lnkDeleteVendor").exists?
    textRow.a(:id => "lnkDeleteVendor").click
  end
```

Thank you.

Comment: Generally I avoid using ID values when it is clear that they are repeated (which is invalid HTML) as most of the code around selecting by ID presumes the value will be unique.   However, by first restricting things to the single row of the table, you should be safe to select as you are doing.   I'd suggest an ELSE for your IF that handles the case of the delete link not being found so that it does not just silently fail the click if that is the case.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried just selecting the row directly based on the included text, and then clicking the link within the row?

```
driver.table(:class => ["table table-striped table-bordered table-hover"])
      .tr(:text => 'TestingName1')
      .i(:class => 'fa-trash')
      .parent
      .click
```

That would be a little easier if there was something about the link element that was unique from the other links in the same row (such as a class, or data- attribute)  as it is we have to locate it via the unique class (within that row) on the italics element within the link.

You could also identify it by index, but if the table is changed or re-arranged then that could easily break your code or click the wrong link.

(warning, above code is untested, written just based on your HTML)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I got it working with a little bit of modification.